# Bash replace Nth word in a string with a variable

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, awk

I need to find Nth word in a string (space delimited) and replace with a variable.
In the below example 4th word needs to be replaced with another string.

```
1 Test 123456 REPLACE_ME 99
```

to

```
1 Test 123456 $STRING_TO_REPLACE 99
```

I was able to find 4th word using `awk '{ print $4}'`, but don't know how to replace with another string variable.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
   replace='replace me'; echo "233131 2 saad four five dssd sdad" |  awk -v r="$replace" '{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { if ( i == 4 )print r;else print $i } }'
```

Comment: `{$4 = r; print}` seems simpler

Answer (score 2):

using awk

```
str="1 Test 123456 REPLACE_ME 99"
STRING_TO_REPLACE="Hello"

echo $str |awk -v r=${STRING_TO_REPLACE} '{$4=r}1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two shell solutions.  The first is a pure sh solution:

```
set -- 1 Test 123456 REPLACE_ME 99
one=$1
two=$2
three=$3
shift 4
echo $one $two $three '$STRING_TO_REPLACE' $*
```

The output is:

```
1 Test 123456 $STRING_TO_REPLACE 99
```

The second is a bash solution:

```
set -- 1 Test 123456 REPLACE_ME 99
echo ${*:1:3} '$STRING_TO_REPLACE' ${*:5:$#}
```

This outputs:

```
1 Test 123456 $STRING_TO_REPLACE 99
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the N-th word, you could do like this:

```
awk -v n=4 -v r="$STRING_TO_REPLACE" '{ $n = r } 1' <<< "$str"
```

Using GNU sed you could replace the 4th word like this:

```
str="1 Test 123456 REPLACE_ME 99"
STRING_TO_REPLACE="Hello"
sed -e "s/\<\w\+/STRING_TO_REPLACE/4" <<< "$str"
```

The pattern there means:

- `\<` -- start of word
- `\w` -- "word character"
- `\+` -- one or more of the previous match
- `\w\+` -- one or more word characters
- The `4` in `s///4` means to perform the replacement for the 4th occurrence only

Comment: Thank you so much! regexp is the most complicated thing in the wordl!

Comment: @user3171185 care to accept one of the good answers? Or perhaps this one? (wink ^ wink ^)

Answer (score 0):

Another pure sh (possibly bash) solution

```
set -- 1 Test 123456 REPLACE_ME 99
set -- "${@:0:4}" SOMETHING_ELSE "${@:5}"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have Ruby

```
# echo "1 Test 123456 REPLACE_ME 99" | ruby -e 'f=gets.split(/\s+/);f[3]="new";puts f.join(" ")'
1 Test 123456 new 99
```